# Skip system checks on Django server in DEBUG mode in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm, pydev

I am running django application in Pycharm in DEBUG mode. 
Each time when i change some code system checks are performed.

```
pydev debugger: process 2354 is connecting

Performing system checks...
```

Is there any way to skip system checks/speed up this checks?

UPDATE: I want to disable system checks after changes in code, because they are too slow.

Comment: How long is it taking that you're finding it problematic?  It takes ~10-15 seconds on the incredibly-badly-written, 250,000 LOC legacy project I'm working on, and even that's only a fairly mild inconvenience.

Comment: It is problematic because each single change in code in debug mode causes system checks performing and it takes time. Can i disable this checks?

Comment: I filed a feature request to Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32296

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### The Problem

Unfortunately, there's no command-line argument or setting you can just turn on in order to turn off the checks in `runserver`. *In general*, there's the `--skip-checks` option which can turn off system checks but they are of no use for `runserver`.

If you read the code of the `runserver` command, you see that it essentially ignores the `requires_system_checks` and `requires_migration_checks` flags but instead explicitly calls `self.check()` and `self.check_migrations()` in its [`inner_run` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.5/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L110), no matter what:

```
def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
    [ Earlier irrelevant code omitted ...]

    self.stdout.write("Performing system checks...\n\n")
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
    # Need to check migrations here, so can't use the
    # requires_migrations_check attribute.
    self.check_migrations()

    [ ... more code ...]
```

#### A Solution

What you could do is **derive your own `run` command, which takes the `runserver` command but overrides the methods that perform the checks**:

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunServer

class Command(RunServer):

    def check(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stdout.write(self.style.WARNING("SKIPPING SYSTEM CHECKS!\n"))

    def check_migrations(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stdout.write(self.style.WARNING("SKIPPING MIGRATION CHECKS!\n"))
```

You need to put this under `<app>/management/commands/run.py` where `<app>` is whatever appropriate app should have this command. Then you can invoke it with `./manage.py run` and you'll get something like:

```
Performing system checks...

SKIPPING SYSTEM CHECKS!

SKIPPING MIGRATION CHECKS!

January 18, 2017 - 12:18:06
Django version 1.10.2, using settings 'foo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: This is awesome! and @s29 if you override django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver instead it will load all of your static files.

Comment: @Mike I wish I saw your message 2h ago, I came back here to provide the same suggestion. I recommend including this here, very easy to miss this and go crazy with Django static files :)

Comment: 2021 here, have a project that would take 2 minutes to restart.  Now 2 seconds. I can't begin to tell you how happy I am. It's like I've been reborn.

Answer (score 2):

There's one thing that might speed up the PyCharm's debugger and that is to turn off the "**Collect run-time types information for code insight**" setting :located under File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger.

Comment: I have previously set this setting and still reloading in debug mode after code change is slow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [Louis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725866/13675449), but it is no longer the case as of django 4.0 that `runserver` command explicitly calls `self.check()`. It now *conditionally* runs based on the `--skip-checks` option.

```py
def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        [ Earlier irrelevant code omitted ...]

        if not options["skip_checks"]:
            self.stdout.write("Performing system checks...\n\n")
            self.check(display_num_errors=True)
        # Need to check migrations here, so can't use the
        # requires_migrations_check attribute.
        self.check_migrations()

         [ ... more code ...]
```

In other words, `python manage.py runserver --skip-checks` will skip system checks.

See the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.0/#management-commands) and the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/14884b6be89963c8ceb2c9da459ed8421aea3bf8/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L131)